# Why can't I access my DataStore when using App Engine in Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible

Hi I've been trying to use Datastore via the App Engine. I deployed (gcloud app deploy) it online but it doesn't access the database. It does when I am on my local dev computer though. I have four routes and two of them access an third party API and return the data I am expecting, but the one accessing the google/datastore just don't work online..

From the logs...

```
2017-06-09 23:02:20 default[20170609t183640]  
"GET /crops/0&begincrops" 502
2017-06-09 23:09:54 default[20170609t183640]  
Error: Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/src/agriapi/node_modules/grpc/src/node/extension_binary/grpc_
node.node)      
at Object.Module._extensions..node (module.js:598:18)      
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)      
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:466:12)      
at Function.Module._load (module.js:458:3)      
at Module.require (module.js:513:17)      
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)      
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/agriapi/node_modules/grpc/src/node/src/grpc_extension.js:38:15)      
at Module._compile (module.js:569:30)      
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)      
at Module.load (module.js:503:32)
```

Comment: Google Support ID:  62496356

Comment: Could it be as simple as a typo?  Is `/0&begincrops` correct?

Comment: It is. At least when the host is localhost. When it's the host given by Google platform it doesn't work for the two paths. One is /crops/ and /tips/